# Can I use SQL LocalDB when creating an exe with Visual Basic 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016, localdb

I am busy with creating a program for which I want to be able to have a database on the NAS and maybe that from 2 or 3 PC I can get access to. But it should be possible that simultaneously 2-3 PC (not more) will have access to this database.

In Visual Basic 2015 I now am using the SQL LocalDB (from SQL Server 2016). Now I have some questions, because I am not that into SQL Server and how the connection is working.

1. Can LocalDB make simultaneously connection with 2-3 pc's?
2. What do I need to do, so I can get a connection that I need. Will the connection string which I now am using in Visual Basic with the LOcalDB automaticly be replaced or do I need to write some extra code for this? Something that I need to write a code to sellect the connection string?
3. Because in principle I don't realy want to work with an Server, but only want to use for home use with DB on a NAS, is there also some alternative for this?

If anybody can help, then please. For I don't want to spend lot of time, working on the project to find in the end out, that this way is not working.

Regards,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB only allows connections from a single PC.

You can use the free SQL Server Express, it must be installed on one of the 2-3 machines sharing data.